# Data access with VS2010 IDE?

Tags: c#, datagridview, sql-server-ce

I'm working on my first C# project which is a small patience management system. I used SQL compact edition as my database. All of the contactings with SQLCE, I did them through the VS2010 IDE which automatically create connection string, manipulating dataset, so forth.
Although it's very convenient to program like this, it's hard for me to modify the data displayed(through datagridview) on the form as I like. So, I want to know where VS2010 store the connection string or query so that I can modify it? It seems to me that VS2010 hide all the details.
P/S: I used ADO.NET to access the database
Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ConnectionString` is stored in the `app.Config` or `web.Config` file.  As for how the data is queryed, that depends on what framework you are using, for example, Entity Frameworks etc.